Known proofs of the 2-dimensional divergence theorem
I'm looking for any known proofs of the following version of the divergence theorem:

Theorem
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a domain such that $\partial \Omega$ (its boundary) is a simple and compact curve. Let $X$ be a differentiable vector field. Then, $$\int_{\Omega} \text{div}\left( X \right) = \int_{\partial \Omega}\left\langle X, N \right\rangle$$
with $N$ being the exterior normal vector to $\Omega$.

I know the existence of a proof similar to the one given in Marsden and Tromba Vector Calculus, but I've been looking for a specific 2D proof and I haven't been able to find it. The one I'm interested in makes use of the following Lemma, derived from Sard's Theorem:

Lemma
Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a simple, compact curve. Then the complement of the following set $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} ~ \mid ~ r(t) = (0,x)\text{ is transversal to } C\right\}$$ is a mesure-zero set.

$C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a simple curve when $\forall p \in C$ there exists an open neighbourhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ differential map $\alpha \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$ such that $\alpha \colon I \to \left( \mathcal{U} \cap C \right)$ is a homeomorphism.
$r(t)$ is transversal to $C$ when either $r(t) \cap C = \emptyset$ or when $r(t)$ is not tangent to $C$ in any $p \in r(t) \cap C$.

Throughout your post you are lacking smoothness assumptions. Please edit everywhere. And why should transversality (which also requires some degree of smoothness) even be relevant?

@TedShifrin Somewhere along the proof I'm looking for I recall expressing the integral of div(X_1) (the divergence of the first component of X) as a sum of several integrals. One of them was over this measure-zero set, so you could discard it and work with the others. I'm sorry for the lack of specificity, it was a proof given to me in a class and I don't recall a lot of details. Thanks for your help.

You still haven't responded to my request for hypotheses. (I see now that you are assuming that the curve is the image of a smooth map.) Only assuming $X$ is differentiable but not $C^1$? And what in the world do you mean in your comment when you refer to the divergence of a scalar function?

Again, I was given this proof a long time ago, so bear with me if I don't explain myself clearly enough. Let X = (X_1, X_2). Then div(X_1)=div(X_1,0)=d/dx1(X_1). That's how you get div(X_1). Differentiable in this case may refer to C^{infty}, I'm not sure. Finally, transversality is relevant because you will integrate div(X_1) throughout non-transversal lines to \partial\Omega. Using the forementioned lemma, you'll reach the desired expression for \int div(X_1) due to some of the terms vanishing.

My professor at that time also mentioned that this proof I'm refering to appeared in a russian calculus book that had to be publidhed before 1989, if that is of any help.

Transversality and Sard's Theorem in a calculus book? Not believable. The only thing I can think of is that we want to define the winding number of $C$ around the origin by taking the degree of the radial projection map from $C$ to the unit circle. The degree will be the signed number of preimages of any regular value (so here the transversality gets invoked, but there's a good deal more work to do). This winding number is given by $\frac1{2\pi}\int_C d\theta$. This line integral can be converted to the flux integral of the rotated vector field.
